# AsyncTask inside of onPostExecute of another Asynctask and return the result

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask, google-places-api

In my first AsyncTask `doInBackground` method I run a method that get a list of places from Google Place Api. Inside the `postExecute` of this first AsyncTask, I get all the names of these places and show them all in a ListView.

I now would like to show the driving distance of a single place from my current location (I can already get it). To do so, I created, in another class, another AsyncTask to get this distance. Here is the code:

```
public class Distance extends AsyncTask<Double, Double, String> {
    GooglePlaces googlePlaces;
    String distancePlace = null;
    @Override
    final protected String doInBackground(Double... params) {
        double lat1,lat2,lon1,lon2;
        lat1=params[0];
        lon1=params[1];
        lat2=params[2];
        lon2=params[3];
        googlePlaces = new GooglePlaces();
        distancePlace= googlePlaces.getDistance(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2);
        return distancePlace;
    }
}
```

and this is the code of my first AsyncTask `postExecute`:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //get json status
                String status = nearPlaces.status;
                if (status.equals("OK")){
                    if (nearPlaces.results != null){
                        //every single place
                        for (Place p : nearPlaces.results){
                        //just a try, here I would like to get the distance
                         /*
                            Double[] myparams = {gps.getLatitude(),gps.getLongitude(),
                                    p.geometry.location.lat,p.geometry.location.lng};
                            new Distance().execute(myparams);*/

                            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                map.put(KEY_NAME,p.name);
                                //add hashmap
                                placesListItems.add(map);
                          }
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(GpsActivity.this, placesListItems, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {KEY_REFERENCE,KEY_NAME},
                                new int[] {R.id.reference, R.id.name});
                        //add into listview
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
```

My problem is how to execute the "distance AsyncTask" inside my postExecute and return its result into my first AsyncTask, to show it in my ListView.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Distance distance = new Distance(){
    protected void onPostExecute(final String result1) {
        // First AsyncTask result.
        Distance distance2 = new Distance(){
            protected void onPostExecute(String result2) {
                // process the second result. 
                // Because the first result "result1" is "final", 
                // it can be accessed inside this method.
            }
        };
        distance2.execute(...);
    }
};
distance.execute(...);
```

Also, you don't need to use `runOnUiThread(...)` because the `onPostExecute(...)` method is executed on the UI thread.

Comment: I don't understand where exactly I have to put your code, just before the `for`? And then put inside `onPostExecute(String result2)` all the rest (`HashMap` etc..)?

Comment: @user6262006 My answer illustrates how you can start an `AsyncTask` when another one finishes and how you can access the results of the first task inside the `onPostExecute(...)` method of the second one. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve so I can't be more specific on how you can use this.

Comment: As you can see in the code I posted, for every place in the list of Place `nearPlaces.result`, I need to execute the `Distance AsyncTask`, which is in another class, not in the same activity, and get the result of the `Distance AsyncTask` for every place, so I can add it to my `HashMap` and show it with the name of the respective place. The `postExecute` method that you can see in my code is from the other AsyncTask, which searches for places.

Comment: @user6262006 You can override the `onPostExecute` method inside the class in which you create the `Distance` object, this method doesn't need to be in the `Distance` class. Also, after the first task finishes, you can create the adapter and set it to the list, then, when each `Distance` task finishes, update the `placesListItems` list (`placesListItems.add(map);`) and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` so that those changes will be reflected in the GUI.

Comment: Are you find a good solution for this? I'm trying to do more or less the same... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553554/my-ui-is-blocked-using-asynctask-with-distancematrix-and-google-maps